# How to compress an image without losing quality in Android?

Tags: android, android-view

I have an image. I want to compress it without losing quality. How can I do it? Please can any one help me?
I am using below code to compress the image.

```
bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), strSignaturePath, 150, 30);
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        String imagepath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath, options);
    // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, imagepath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath, options);
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(Options options, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below tools [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/), [PNGCRUSH](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) and enjoy!!